# Counting Features of Subsets

Tags: combinatorics

1. How many subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ are there that do not contain two consecutive integers?  Include the empty set, too.
2. For any nonempty set $T$ whose elements are positive integers, define $f(T)$ to be the square of the product of the elements of $T$. For example, if $T=\{1,3,6\}$, then $f(T)=(1\cdot 3\cdot 6)^2 = 18^2 = 324$.
   Consider the nonempty subsets $T$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ that do not contain two consecutive integers. If we compute $f(T)$ for each such set, then add up the resulting values, what do we get?

Is there a major induction that I'm missing because I don't see any.  Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For part two consider the recurrence $$A_n = A_{n - 1} + (1 + A_{n - 2}) \times n^2$$ where $A_1 = 1$ and $A_2 = 5.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,7\}$ without two consecutive integers is the same as the number of strings with length $7$ over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ without two consecutive $1$s (if we consider some element, we "mark it" with a $1$). Let $S_n$ be the number of strings with length $n$ with the same property. We have $S_1=2$, $S_2=3$ and $S_{n}=S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}$ for any $n\geq 3$, since a valid string may start only with a $0$ or with $10$. It follows that $S_n=F_{n+2}$ and $S_7=F_9=\color{red}{34}$.

For part $2$, there is Marko Riedel's hint. Let we say that a set is *special* if it does not have consecutive elements and let
$$ A_n = \sum_{\substack{A\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}\\A \text{ special}}}\prod_{a\in A}a^2. $$
There are just two cases: $n$ is an element of a special set in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ or it is not.
 According to such observation, we have
$$ A_1=1,\quad A_2 =5,\qquad A_{n}=A_{n-1}+n^2(1+A_{n-2}) $$ 
hence $A_7=\color{red}{40319}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n$ be the collection of subsets of $\lbrace 1,\dots,n \rbrace$ that do not contain two consecutive integers.

$S_0$ is the set $\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace,$ and $S_1$ is $\big\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace 1 \rbrace \big\rbrace.$

For $n\ge 2,$  $S_{n}=S_{n-1} \bigcup \big\lbrace X \cup \lbrace n \rbrace \vert X \in S_{n-2}\big\rbrace.$

That's enough to get an induction going to compute the numbers that you're interested in.

(Thank you to @Shagnik for pointing out that I had misread the problem as asking to count only non-empty subsets.)

Comment: You could instead let $S_n$ be the collection of subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ without consecutive elements (including the empty set).  Then you wouldn't have to add the set $\{ \{n\} \}$ at the end.

Comment: @Shagnik: Yes, I phrased it this way because the problem asked for the number of non-empty sets with the property, and it seemed more direct not to have to make an adjustment at the end.  But either way works.

Comment: Part 1 does ask for the empty set to be included, but perhaps this was a recent edit.

Comment: You're right -- I must have misread it.